# How can I add this external library in my C code?

Tags: c, interpolation, configure, bspline

I have the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void pusher(int part, int ntime,long double x[3], long double v[3], long double E[3], long double B[3], long double Vth, long double c2, long double x_new[3], long double v_new[3]){

   long double x_mid[3];
   long double upart_new[3];

    // half time-step for Euler step
     long double dth = 0.5*dt;
    
    // position x_{i+1/2} 
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        x_mid[i] = x[i] + v[i]*dth;
    }
 
   // Get E, B at new position 
   // This is where I would like to add a function of that library
   // interpolate_fields();
   

    Vay(v, E, B, c2, upart_new);   // A function of mine 
                                   // not necessary to include here

    long double gL_new = gamma_u(upart_new, c2);
    // full position update at t_{i+1} = t_{i+1/2} + dt/2 = t_i + dt
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        v_new[i]  = upart_new[i]/gL_new; 
        x_new[i]  = x_mid[i] + v_new[i]*dth;
        
   }

}




int main(){
    // ++ Define variables //
    for (int nt = 0; nt < nsteps; nt++){
        
        for (int particle = 0; particle < Np; particle++){
    
             // ++ Other functions //

            pusher( particle, nt,x, v, E, B, Vth, c2,  x_new,v_new);

             // ++ Other functions //

          }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to utilize the Einspline library found here:

http://einspline.sourceforge.net/index.shtml

More specifically I would like to use the 3D interpolation function this library offers.

I am new to C and I am having a really hard time configuring the library to my system and adding the required function to my code. Any help?

I ve made it to step 9 where I need to type make install! I get the following error:

```
(cd .libs && rm -f libeinspline.la && ln -s ../libeinspline.la libeinspline.la)
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math -g -MT time_multi.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/time_multi.Tpo -c -o time_multi.o time_multi.c
time_multi.c: In function ‘test_3d_real_float_all’:
time_multi.c:1168:54: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1168 |    eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s (multi_spline, x, y, z, multi_vals);
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                     |
      |                                                     _Complex float *

In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:89:22: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
   89 |      float* restrict vals);
      |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1170:53: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1170 |  eval_UBspline_3d_s (norm_splines[j], x, y, z, &(norm_vals[j]));
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                |
      |                                                _Complex float *

In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:403:23: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  403 |       float* restrict val)
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
time_multi.c:1181:7: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vg’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1181 |       multi_vals, multi_grads);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
      |       |
      |       _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:94:25: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
   94 |         float* restrict vals,
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1181:19: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vg’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1181 |       multi_vals, multi_grads);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:95:25: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
   95 |         float* restrict grads);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
time_multi.c:1183:56: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vg’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1183 | val_UBspline_3d_s_vg (norm_splines[j], x, y, z, &(norm_vals[j]),
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 _Complex float *

In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:467:20: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  467 |    float* restrict val, float* restrict grad)
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
time_multi.c:1184:6: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vg’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1184 |      &(norm_grads[3*j]));
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |      |
      |      _Complex float *
In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:467:41: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  467 |    float* restrict val, float* restrict grad)
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1201:7: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vgl’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1201 |       multi_vals, multi_grads, multi_lapl);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
      |       |
      |       _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:100:26: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  100 |          float* restrict vals,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1201:19: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vgl’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1201 |       multi_vals, multi_grads, multi_lapl);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:101:26: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  101 |          float* restrict grads,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
time_multi.c:1201:32: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vgl’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1201 |       multi_vals, multi_grads, multi_lapl);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:102:26: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  102 |          float* restrict lapl);
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1203:57: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgl’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1203 | al_UBspline_3d_s_vgl (norm_splines[j], x, y, z, &(norm_vals[j]),
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 _Complex float *

In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:576:20: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  576 |    float* restrict val, float* restrict grad, float* restrict lapl)
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
time_multi.c:1204:6: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgl’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1204 |      &(norm_grads[3*j]), &(norm_lapl[j]));
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |      |
      |      _Complex float *
In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:576:41: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  576 |    float* restrict val, float* restrict grad, float* restrict lapl)
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1204:26: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgl’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1204 |      &(norm_grads[3*j]), &(norm_lapl[j]));
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                          |
      |                          _Complex float *
In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:576:63: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  576 | ct val, float* restrict grad, float* restrict lapl)
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

time_multi.c:1225:7: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vgh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1225 |       multi_vals, multi_grads, multi_hess);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~
      |       |
      |       _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:107:26: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  107 |          float* restrict vals,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1225:19: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vgh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1225 |       multi_vals, multi_grads, multi_hess);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:108:26: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  108 |          float* restrict grads,
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
time_multi.c:1225:32: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘eval_multi_UBspline_3d_s_vgh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1225 |       multi_vals, multi_grads, multi_hess);
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                                |
      |                                _Complex float *
In file included from multi_bspline.h:33,
                 from time_multi.c:21:
multi_bspline_eval_s.h:109:26: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  109 |          float* restrict hess);
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1227:57: warning: passing argument 5 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1227 | al_UBspline_3d_s_vgh (norm_splines[j], x, y, z, &(norm_vals[j]),
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 _Complex float *

In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:739:20: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  739 |    float* restrict val, float* restrict grad, float* restrict hess)
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
time_multi.c:1228:6: warning: passing argument 6 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1228 |      &(norm_grads[3*j]), &(norm_hess[9*j]));
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |      |
      |      _Complex float *
In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:739:41: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  739 |    float* restrict val, float* restrict grad, float* restrict hess)
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
time_multi.c:1228:26: warning: passing argument 7 of ‘eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgh’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 1228 |      &(norm_grads[3*j]), &(norm_hess[9*j]));
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                          |
      |                          _Complex float *
In file included from bspline.h:50,
                 from time_multi.c:22:
bspline_eval_std_s.h:739:63: note: expected ‘float * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘_Complex float *’
  739 | ct val, float* restrict grad, float* restrict hess)
      |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~

time_multi.c: At top level:
time_multi.c:2780:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 2780 | main()
      | ^~~~
mv -f .deps/time_multi.Tpo .deps/time_multi.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math -g   -o time_multi time_multi.o libeinspline.la -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath   -lm
gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -malign-double -fstrict-aliasing -ffast-math -g -o .libs/time_multi time_multi.o  ./.libs/libeinspline.so -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_2d_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:213: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_s_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:233: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_s_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:257: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_s_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_3d_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:343: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:356: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:376: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:400: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_2d_double_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:633: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_d_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:653: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_d_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:677: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_d_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_3d_double_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:765: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:785: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:809: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_2d_complex_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1021: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_c_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1051: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_c_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1080: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_c_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_3d_real_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1170: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1183: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1203: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1227: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_3d_complex_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1307: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_c'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1320: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_c_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1340: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_c_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1364: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_c_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_complex_double':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1442: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1474: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_2d_complex_double_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1680: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_z_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1700: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_z_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1729: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_2d_z_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `time_3d_complex_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1831: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_c'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1885: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_c_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `time_3d_real_float_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:1973: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2006: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_s_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `time_3d_real_double_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2102: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2135: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `time_3d_complex_double_all':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2228: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2282: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_complex_double_vgh':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2357: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2408: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_double':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2479: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2511: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d'
/usr/bin/ld: time_multi.o: in function `test_double_vgh':
/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2583: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: /mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src/time_multi.c:2638: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_d_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_z_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_c_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_c'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_s'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_d_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_s_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_s_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_z_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_z_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_z'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_s_vg'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_z_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_z_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_c_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_c_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_d'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_UBspline_3d_z_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_d_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_s_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_s_vgh'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_2d_d_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_c_vgl'
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libeinspline.so: undefined reference to `eval_NUBspline_3d_c_vgh'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:661: time_multi] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:515: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/nikos.000/RMHD_test_part/test_part_code/einspline-0.9.2/src'
make: *** [Makefile:298: all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you follow the [instructions](http://einspline.sourceforge.net/doc.shtml) precisely?

Comment: @ bereal I am not sure, should I add something before the ./configure? I am really new to linux. I am not exactly sure what ./configure is supposed to do! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `./configure` is supposed to run the script named `configure` in the current directory, which will prepare the build. So, according to the instructions: 1) download the archive source, 2) unpack the archive, 3) `cd` into the unpacked, 4) run `./configure`, etc. I'm not familiar with the library, but it seems that it may require installing a Fortran compiler first.

Comment: `einspline-0.5.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar (child)` you did not download the tar, it's not there.

Comment: Thanks everyone I ve made it to step 8 where I need to type make! I get the following error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.    Any suggestions?

Comment: I had to install gfortran and have now made it to the last step, make install. Where I get the error shown in the updated question